# AutoTest and Rspec testing with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, autotest

I just started using AutoTest. As far as i can tell i have everything configured, but everytime i run *autotest* then i get the following error coming from my test_helper.rb:

```
richards-macbook-pro: $ autotest 
loading autotest/rails
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit test/unit/link_test.rb test/functional/links_controller_test.rb test/unit/tagging_test.rb test/functional/tag_controller_test.rb test/unit/tag_test.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u
./test/unit/../test_helper.rb:26: undefined method `use_transactional_fixtures=' for Test::Unit::TestCase:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from ./test/unit/link_test.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from -e:1
    from -e:1:in `each'
    from -e:1

================================================================================
```

I thought this was curious, and I'm just starting to use rspec to test rather than the traditional rails tools. I attempted removing the entire test folder from my project (but keeping my spec/ folder) and when i do that autotest will never fully launch:

```
richards-macbook-pro: $ autotest 
loading autotest/rails
```

Even if i save something in my spec folder, it won't update. This doesn't seem to be common, does anyone know a possible work around to this, or maybe a way to just tell autottest to only look at my /spec folder???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have done

```
./script/generate rspec
```

in your rails app, You can use

```
autospec
```

to make you specs run automatically.

HTH

Comment: Does not work for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686907/invalid-option-autospec