# invalid option: --autospec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build-automation, rspec, cucumber, autotest

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby -rrubygems -e "require 'redgreen'"  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/bin/spec --autospec <files_here> -O spec/spec.opts

invalid option: --autospec
Test::Unit automatic runner.
Usage: -e [options] [-- untouched arguments]

which spec says "/usr/local/bin/spec"
which autospec says "/usr/local/bin/autospec"

/usr/local/bin/spec --help includes --autospec option in the list.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got some time during the weekend to look into this myself.

The problem is "require 'redgreen/autotest'" statement in .autotest file
I keep my autotest configuration in ~/.autotest

Comment that row and "autospec", "autotest", and "cucumber" works ok.

Comment: and it's still colorized output!

Comment: have not tried but you may check the -rredgreen in cucumber profiles

Answer (score 2):

You can just require redgreen conditionally

```
require 'redgreen/autotest' unless ENV['RSPEC']
```

You can have coloured output in rspec by passing **--color** in your *spec.opts* file

Comment: I do have "--color" and "--colour" (just in case) options in spec.opts, but it does not give me colored specs/units, just gives colored cucumbers